# Mustache templates + Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, mustache

Is there a way to use Mustache templates with Sencha Touch? Like to overwrite the Ext.XTemplate class to use mustaches..

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://cliffmeyers.com/2012/3/29/integrating-sencha-touch-and-hoganjs-for-easy-html-templatin.html) has a pretty good solution. Albeit only for hogan.js, it can easily be modified to work with mustache.